# Merge Partitions Server 2003

Tags: merge-replication

I just installed new 500gig drives to replace 160gig drives in my RAID server running Windows 2003 Server.

I was wondering if someone could recommend a utility program that would help me recover all the new space on the new drives and also to merge my existing 2 partitions into one.  I know I could just reinstall everything but I was hoping there was a reasonably priced utility program I could buy to do the work.

I'm running a RAID mirror with 2 drives.

Answer (score 1):

Partition Magic.

It's not for sale any more, but I always have a copy on a floppy disk for emergencies (and in the last 5 years on a bootable CD).

That said I'm sure there's millions of other freeware tools that do the same thing.

Comment: +1 I wouldn't be without it.

Answer (score 0):

gparted should let you merge partitions- it's free so buyer beware (you can't use the latest version as it's known to hose NTFS) Diskpart should let you extend the partitions so long as your raid controller lets the OS see the new space- not all do.